# How to create a self defined series in Pine on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script

i'm pretty new to pine scripts, and i have a very simple problem: i want to multiply each value of a series by a different value, e.g., i have the series sma(close, 10) and i want to multiply each of its values with a different value. Therefore, i thought to generate another series with the different factors and multiply the two series.

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = sma(close, 10) * values

This is what i tried so far, but i get an error when i try to initiate the series with [. Any help on how to construct such a series?

Cheers

Marc

Answer (score 2):

In pinescript the syntax `[a,b,...]` is used when a function return a multi dimensional array, that is: `[a,b] = f(x)`, where `f(x) => [x+1,x+2]` for example, so its not like with other programming languages.

Also note that in your case you must assume that your series `sma(close,10)` contain only 10 values, which is not necessarily the case. So one way to possibly do it is to simply use `sma(close,10)*(bar_index+1)` where your wanted results will appear when `bar_index+1` is inferior to 11.

Another way is to use:

```
a = bar_index%10 + 1
result = sma(close,10)*a
```

Here `a` is will start at 1 and increase by 1 until `a = 10`, then it will be equal to 1 once again, this process will repeat itself until the last bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if the array that i want to multiply with is not [1, 2, 3, ..., 10] but for example the fibonacci numbers? How would i then creat the series that i use as a factor?

Comment: You could use the Fibonacci sequence, however it would converge toward a pretty large number and i think Tradingview will return "na" when a number is too large. As such you would need to set the bar number at which the series will start, for example : "fib = bar_index > start ? fib calculation : na" , then "prod = fib*sma(close,10)".

Comment: fib = 0,
fib := bar_index > start ? nz(fib[1],1) + nz(fib[2]) : na

Answer (score 0):

Go back to last 10 candles and start incrementing the counter.

```
var count = 0
if last_bar_index - bar_index < 10
    count := count + 1
```

Use the counter as index into array to get values. The values in the series will be 'na' prior to last 10 candles.

```
series = array.size(values)>0 and (last_bar_index - bar_index) < 10? array.get(values ,count) : na
```

The series variable above can be used in any ta functions to do calculations.

```
daily_func() =>
    var count = 0
    values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    if last_bar_index - bar_index < 10
        count := count + 1
    series = array.size(values)>0 and (last_bar_index - bar_index) < 10? array.get(values ,count) : na
    [series]

[series] = request.security('SPX', 'D', daily_func())
```